# How to read arbitrary amounts of data directly from a file in Go?

Tags: go, byte

Without reading the contents of a file into memory, how can I read "x" bytes from the file so that I can specify what x is for every separate read operation?

I see that the `Read` method of various `Reader`s takes a byte slice of a certain length and I can read from a file into that slice. But in that case the size of the slice is fixed, whereas what I would like to do, ideally, is something like:

```
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("./file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    someBytes := f.Read(2)
    someMoreBytes := f.Read(4)
}
```

`bytes.Buffer` has a `Next` [method](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer.Next) which behaves very closely to what I would want, but it requires an existing buffer to work, whereas I'm hoping to read an arbitrary amount of bytes from a file without needing to read the whole thing into memory.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See [`io.CopyN`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#CopyN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function:

```
// readN reads and returns n bytes from the reader.
// On error, readN returns the partial bytes read and
// a non-nil error.
func readN(r io.Reader, n int) ([]byte, error) {
    // Allocate buffer for result
    b := make([]byte, n)
    // ReadFull ensures buffer is filled or error is returned.
    n, err := io.ReadFull(r, b) 
    return b[:n], err
}
```

Call like this:

```
someBytes, err := readN(f, 2)
if err != nil  { /* handle error here */
someMoreBytes := readN(f, 4)
if err != nil  { /* handle error here */
```

Comment: This is causing allocation on the heap so a frequent use of this function will generate a lot of garbage on the heap…

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
f, err := os.Open("/tmp/dat")
check(err)
b1 := make([]byte, 5)
n1, err := f.Read(b1)
check(err)
fmt.Printf("%d bytes: %s\n", n1, string(b1[:n1]))
```

for more reading please check [site](https://gobyexample.com/reading-files).